# Hibernate expecting "all", found '(' - what does this mean?

Tags: java, hibernate, join, hql, fetch

I'm getting this error and I can't find any reference to it:

```
    org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: expecting "all", found '(' near line 1, column 221 [select new EffectivePermissions(r.id, r.name, r.defaultValue, rc.value AS companyValue, ru.value AS userValue) from permissionsPackage.Entity.Permissions r left join permissionsPackage.Entity.CompanyPermissions rc fetch (r.id=rc.permissionId AND rc.companyId=2313 ) left join permissionsPackage.Entity.UserPermissions ru fetch (r.id=ru.permissionId AND ru.userId=1)]
 at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:54)
 at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:47)
 at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:79)
```

Below is the Query I'm using.

```
  this.hql = "select new EffectivePermissions(r.id, r.name, r.defaultValue, rc.value AS companyValue, ru.value AS userValue) "
            + "from "
            + Permissions.class.getName()
            + " r "
            + "left join "
            + CompanyPermissions.class.getName()
            + " rc "
            + "fetch (r.id=rc.permissionId AND rc.companyId="
            + user.getCompany().getId()
            + " ) "
            + "left join "
            + UserPermissions.class.getName()
            + " ru "
            + "fetch (r.id=ru.permissionId AND ru.userId="
            + user.getId()
            + ")";

    Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);

    permissions = query.list();
```

I have a class called EffectivePermission with the properties in the constructor and I'd like to get a list based on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Hibernate Reference chapter [14.3. Associations and joins](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-joins):

> A "fetch" join allows associations or collections of values to be initialized along with their parent objects using a single select ... See Section 19.1, “Fetching strategies” for more information.

You'll also see there that it must be used after the `join`keyword as in `from e1 left join fetch e2`. It can also be used as in `from entity fetch all properties` (this is why Hibernate is expecting the `all` keyword).

Regarding your specific query, and as far as I know, with HQL you can not specify the join conditions. Hibernate will automatically perform the join using the conditions configured in the mapping. This is why it is necessary to have relationships mapped in order to use a HQL join.

And most importantly, remember that joins in HQL are quite different. You don't join two entities, you join an entity with one of its collection-valued properties (associations). Notice you can always do *cartesian-like* joins (pay attention to performance and always look at the generated queries and execution plans).

As a side note, it can be considered bad practice to append parameter values directly into the query (due to potential injection vulnerabilities). You should be using named parameters instead.